# How to check why certain class fixes my issue?

Tags: html, css

I have pagination with DataTables. I noticed the pagination is broken (The text of the buttons is misaligned or it's out of the button border)

I noticed that whenever I add `disabled` class to the wrapping `<li>` of each button, it fixes it.

But I tried looking in the devtools why and couldn't figure out how to find it.

What is a good way to check why this class "fixes" my issue? (The `disabled` class is added automatically by DataTables to some buttons in the pagination depending on the page)

Comment: You compare the computed CSS values when the class is applied with the computed CSS values when the class is not applied.

Comment: Thanks! So I will have to compare side by side and one by one? Or there's a more convenient way?

Comment: That's up to you. I'd probably copy the values to two text files and use a diff tool on those.

Comment: thank you, and if I do find the culprit, what's the best practice to add these styles assuming the datatable is added dynamically so I can't add styles inline on the pagination `<li>` elements?

Comment: There's no such thing as best practice, just opinions of people who get paid to write them up as "white papers" with titles that contain the words "best practice" :). Just add CSS to your site's stylesheet that uses selectors that are higher in specificity than those used by DataTables.